# Missing link between own repo and upstream repo

Tags: git, github

Here's my typical git workflow using git in steps.

git fork to my own repo

`git clone [ur]` //from my own repo

`git checkout -b new-feature-abc`

`git add . && git commit -m 'done'`

`git push -u origin new-feature-abc` //to my own repo

then I do a PR to upstream, created new-feature-abc on upstream repo
merge to upstream staging branch

I have a problem now, I didn't do git fork, but I did a git clone on my local, how do I do a PR to upstream repo now? I've linkage to upstream, I can see them using `git remote -v`, I can pull from the repo but can't do PR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> exactly, I did not fork that's the problem. So now I have to recreate the fork? –

You can still fork the repo, and then modify your own local cloned repo to reference that fork:

```
git remote rename origin upstream
git remote set-url /url/of/the/fork
```

From there, you are good to go, and can push back to origin (your fork) a dedicated branch.
And you can make a PR back to the original repo.

Comment: how can I move my changes on local repo to that forked branch?

Comment: @SharonChai simply by pushing back as usual: your origin now points to your fork, that you own.

Comment: thanks for your help, this is very straight forward, I got the point. I pushed the changes to my fork then deleted the old repo.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, to do a PR on github from a repository that's not the owners, requires a 'github fork'.

You can still correct this by creating this fork, and pushing your new branch to it first.

Comment: exactly, I did not fork that's the problem. So now I have to recreate the fork?

Comment: exactly. That's what I literally said in my answer.